# Android - Place image in relativeLayout with proper size

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a android card view. Here is the code that I have now:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_card_bg">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/test_img" />
....
```

and the UI looks like:

[image]

However this is not what I am looking for. I want the image to be placed on top of the card, with the top, right, left margins to be `10dip` from the background card boarder. 

Meanwhile, I want to keep the ratio of the image, so don't want to hard-code the width/height of the image view. I want the image width to fit the width of the background card, and the height should be adjusted according to the width.

How should I change the layout parameters to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Try adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and/or `android:scaleType="fitStart"` to your ImageView in xml.

Comment: @MikeOrtiz Hi thanks for the comment, android:adjustViewBounds="true" works!

Comment: Great I'll post it as an answer

Comment: I think there is also need the android:scaleType="fitXY" which always maintain the size .

Comment: @AllanJiang If my answer solved your problem, you should accept it to help others with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your ImageView in xml in order to let the ImageView adjust its bounds.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy......... please do this thing. Replace your imageview code using this one

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/test_img" />
```

If my answer will help you then support this.

Thanks!!!

Comment: fitXY will skew the aspect ratio which is not what he is looking for.